# How to pause a thread instantly?

Tags: android, thread-safety

I have a thread with boolean field "paused" which I use to pause the thread.

```
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        if (!paused) {
            //HERE I do some operations
        }
    }
}
```

But this solution give me a problem:

when I press a button that assigns true to the field "paused", the thread before going on pause completes all operations in the if block.

What can I do to pause instantly the thread?

OR

What can I do to force the button callback to be executed at the end of the current iteration?

**EDIT:**

I solved in this manner:

```
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        synchronized(paused) {
            if (!paused) {
            //HERE I do some operations
            }
        }
    }
}

public void disablePause() {
    synchronized(paused) {
        paused = false;
    }
}

public void pause() {
    synchronized(paused) {
        paused = true;
    }
}
```

paused now is a Boolean object. The main UI thread that executes the button callback function (that call pause(), do some operations and call disablePause()), waits until paused is released by my custom thread(that is at the end of current iteration of while loop). I have still a doubt:
is it a good practice?

Comment: I don't see any situation where it would make sense to "pause" a thread. Just cancel it, store where you where and when you restart, continue from there.

Comment: I need to pause my game loop thread when I press restart level button. The button callback pauses the thread, restart the level and then resumes the thread.

Comment: I guess the GameLoop does you rendering and physics?

Answer (score 0):

*Pausing* a thread instantly is a little complicated. The problem here is, that you would need to check after *every* line if the boolean had changed. And that does not cover the time the program is *in* one of the actual methods that are called from your thread.

If you need the thread to end instantly, **cancel it**. This will interrupt the work done on that thread and it's instantly stopped. After that, you'd have to restart it.

If the reason why it hast to be instantly is, that you're freeing/unvalidating resources instantly when the pause-button is hit: Don't do that.

The best way is to design your game-loop to only do any "changing of level" or other re-configuration stuff at the start of your `while`-loop. When the loop is starting a new cycle, it should **guarantee** that the cycle is going to be executed completely.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but is this the only solution? Really Isn't there a way to synchronize the thread and the button callback function?

Comment: I'd say no and I would really not go the extra mile. You may also want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245098/pausing-a-thread-on-java

Comment: I will see your link tomorrow (here it's 1am). Thank you.